# Anyone have camera specs for the iPhone 6 Plus?

Tags: camera

I've been having a hard time finding good and consistent numbers for the focal length and sensor sizes for the iPhone 6 Plus and it isn't one of the built-in presets in Blender.  Any help would be appreciated.

This is a hugely popular phone on which a lot of footage is being shot.  Blender ships with presets for numerous cameras for camera matching in the scripts/presets/camera directory, including the iPhone_4.py, iPhone_4S.py, and iPhone_5.py files as well as a number of presets for Android phones.

If we can get definitive values I can contribute back an iPhone_6_Plus.py that could ship with Blender and allow a vast amount of extant and future footage to be matched properly.

Comment: http://www.phonearena.com/phones/Apple-iPhone-6_id8346 says the sensor is 1/3" and has a focal length equivalent to 29mm on a 35mm sensor. According to http://www.digified.net/focallength/ 1/3" gives a crop factor of 7.2, which translates to an actual focal length of ~4mm.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about blender, it is about camera specifications.

Comment: If you are trying to camera-match, you should also remember that the iPhone crops the video capture slightly to compensate for stabilization. So the effective focal length is a little longer than the 4mm quoted.

Comment: This question is not off-topic because Blender does not come with a preset for the iPhone 6 Plus on which a *huge* amount of footage is being shot.  I am asking for a definitive answer so that I can provide an iPhone_6_Plus.py that people can drop into the scripts/presets/camera folder.

Comment: @RayMairlot - blender contains camera specifications for over 30 cameras, the iphone6 is not one of them. The tracking camera presets are used for motion tracking, lack of good camera specs can cause tracking to fail or be hard to get right, which does make this blender related. I see no harm in trying to collect more information here before submitting an update patch that Chuck has offered. Someone here may have settings that have been tested to work well with the iphone6.

Comment: In light of the OP's edit and comment and the point made by @sambler, I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Chuck While this is certainly useful information for blender users, I don't see why you expect to find the answer on a blender site. I suggest you search/ask around on sites specializing in the hardware you want to know about. e.g. the [apple](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [photography](http://photo.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange sites.

Comment: Just because the *output* of the question would be useful to blender does not mean the question itself is about blender. There are many complex mathematical algorithms that could be of benefit to blender, but a question about such an algorithm would still be more suited to another stack exchange, regardless of its usefulness.

Comment: I guess I'll ask in apple or photography how to translate the published camera specs to a form that Blender can ingest.  No doubt that will be considered on topic there.  Thanks to those who tried to help.

Comment: Perhaps dividing it into two questions would be better. Ask on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) if anybody knows the data you need, and once you have that data, somebody here may be able to tell you how to incorporate it into Blender. I considered flagging for mod attention and suggesting migrating to Ask Different, but I'm doubting that the people over there will consider the question on topic in its current form.

Comment: Well, the published specs are out there in a different form than Blender wants.  We have a partial answer in these comments from SixthOfFour and a caveat from Mike Pan.  I just need the Blender-specific answer.

Comment: sensor is 6mm focal length is 5.93 .  lens distortion polynomial k1 = 0.039, k2 = -0.003 k3 = 0.000336